# What does "let me have it" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, let

Consider this conversation:

Person A:

> I used to work til 3am then walk home in -20 or better windchills, with the wind blasting ice in your face (it's no longer fair to call it snow at that temperature, it's just tiny shards of ice) and I loved it. It makes me feel capable and alive, and better than southerners. Like maybe I could make it in the arctic.

Person B:

> It makes you feel better than southerners?

Person A:

> Yup, what do they have? Horrific insects, which is something I wouldn't tolerate, so maybe they're tough in their own way, but whatever. **Let me have it.**

When person A said *let me have it*, does it mean something like *let me win this argument*?

Comment: Where did you hear this conversation? Context, please!

Comment: Their comments made by users lananaroux and axxxie on [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/1p8n3a/this_clothing_store_has_a_20c_freezing_chamber/) Reddit post, which is the tenth comment down from the top.

Comment: I think that person means, _"Let me have that cold weather. [I can take the cold.]"_ I think he's referring to the -20C cold weather chamber. Hard to say for sure, though. My second guess would be, _"Go ahead, berate me for how I just insulted southeners."_

Comment: @J.R. I think it's entirely plausible that the meaning is more along the lines of “let me have this”, as in “at least allow me this solace.”

Comment: My guess: Let me have the better feeling than southerners.

Comment: [Let him have it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_Him_Have_It)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am Lananaroux or Person A in this situation.  Tyler James Young is correct as to what I meant by "Let me have it."

In my comment, I conceded that Southerners really do deal with quite a lot in terms of weather and surviving nature and the elements.  However, I intended to imply that feeling like I'm hardier than Southerners during the winter months helps me feel strong enough to endure our long, cold winters.  When I said "Let me have it" I meant: "Please just let me think that I am stronger for living here, where it is cold, than if I moved south, where it is warm, because whether or not it is true, the thought helps me through the winter."

I'd rather not be burdened with the truth of the matter, I would rather just have my feeling of superiority whether or not it is actually valid.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by, Lananaroux! I'm glad we were able to get such a thoughtful explanation from the source of the quotation—that's almost never the case.